# Как заполнить ContextMenuStrip в XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

Я создал приложение WPF c `NotifyIcon` для работы в трее.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public NotifyIcon NotifyIcon { get; } = new NotifyIcon
    {
        Icon = Properties.Resources.status_on_ico,
        Visible = true
    };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NotifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = MyContextMenuStrip;
        NotifyIcon.Click += NotifyIcon_Click;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
    }
}
```

XAML главного окна тривиален и нерелевантен.

Я хочу создать `ContextMenuStrip` для `NotifyIcon` в XAML (Я знаю как это сделать в коде C#, но не хочу).

Вот что у меня получилось.

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:ContextMenuStrip x:Name="MyContextMenuStrip" TopLevel="False">
        <wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
            <!-- Как сюда добавлять элементы -->
        </wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
    </wf:ContextMenuStrip>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Вопрос в том, как добавлять элементы в `ContextMenuStrip.Items` c `Name` и обработчиком события `Click` в XAML?

Comment: Это не смотрели: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472655/6766879 ? Там в исходниках есть и примеры использования.

Comment: Смотрел, но я не уверен в жизнеспособности и надёжности этого компонента, да и не вижу смысла рисковать (так как мне нужен базовый функционал).

Comment: Вообще вопрос в создании контесктного меню из Windows Forms в XAML, на C# это проще простого (поэтому вопрос скорее для того, чтобы сделать покрасивей, а не о том как сделать хоть как-то). Вообще компоненты Windows Forms прекрасно себя чувствуют в WPF и я не являюсь приверженцем "чистоты" WPF.

Comment: Ну судя по MSDN ContextMenuStrip.Items не имеет сеттера, поэтому в разметке нельзя туда ничего записать, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390493/1548895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил [ответ на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44414741/1548895).

> Вопрос в том, как добавлять элементы в `ContextMenuStrip.Items` c `Name` и обработчиком события `Click` в XAML?

Попробуйте это:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:ContextMenuStrip x:Name="MyContextMenuStrip" TopLevel="False">
        <wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
            <wf:ToolStripMenuItem Text="test1" Click="It_Click" />
            <wf:ToolStripMenuItem Text="test2" />
        </wf:ContextMenuStrip.Items>
    </wf:ContextMenuStrip>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

---

```
private void It_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("click!");
}
```